# Re-use a controlled component's logic

Tags: reactjs, typescript

#### Context

I created a custom slider component able to render 2 handles on the slider. A user can chose two values on the same `<input type="range">`. I want this re-usable component to also manage a `minAllowedRange` and `maxAllowedRange` which are respectively a range each handle must stay in.

```js
const MyComponent: FC<MyProps> = ({
    minValue,
    maxValue,
    minAllowedRange,
    maxAllowedRange,
    onChange,
}) => {
    
    const handleOnChangeMin = (event) => {
        // Some basic math to check if the new position is in range before calling onChange
        let newMin = Math.min(+event.target.value, minAllowedRange.min);
        newMin = Math.max(newMin, minAllowedRange.max);

        if (newMin !== minValue) {
             onChange(newMin, maxValue);
        }
    }

    const handleOnChangeMax = (event) => {
        // Some basic math to check if the new position is in range before calling onChange
        let newMax = Math.max(+event.target.value, maxAllowedRange.min);
        newMax = Math.min(newMax, maxAllowedRange.max);     

        if (newMax !== maxValue) {
             onChange(minValue, newMax);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="range" value={minValue} onChange={handleOnChangeMin}/>
            <input type="range" value={maxValue} onChange={handleOnChangeMax}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Now let's say I have a parent *container* that has 2 buttons, one to decrease the `minValue` and one to increase it.

```js
const MyParent: FC<MyProps> = () => {
    const [minValue, setMinValue] = useState(1);
    const [maxValue, setMaxValue] = useState(7);
    const minAllowedRange = { min: 0, max: 4 };
    const maxAllowedRange = { min: 6, max: 10 };
    
    const handleOnChange = (min, max) => {
        setMinValue(min);
        setMaxValue(max);
    }

    const decreaseMin = () => {
        setMinValue(minValue - 1);
    }

    const increaseMin = () => {
        setMinValue(minValue + 1);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={decreaseMin} />
            <MyComponent
                minValue={minValue}
                maxValue={maxValue}
                minAllowedRange={minAllowedRange}
                maxAllowedRange={maxAllowedRange}
                onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
            <button onClick={increaseMin} />
        </>
    )
}
```

This `increaseMin` button would allow the `minValue` to exceed its own allowed range.

#### Question

Is it a common practice to valid some input in a controlled component ? Can you have a *hybrid*-style like here ? If so, is there a built-in way in react to re-use that logic ?

Comment: The answer is: _it depends_. So having a contrived example is hard to give advice about. Can you elaborate more on your question with maybe a real world minimal example of the kind of data you are working with?

Comment: Hello, thanks for you comment. I gave a real world-example of my issue. I omitted a few stuff, like the handles can't cross themselves, but it's basically the same kind of feature I've shown in my example.